# Wifi - networks disappeared

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, network-interface

After succesfull driver installation and a few days with no problem working system can't find wifi networks anymore:
System: Debian 11, kernel: 5.10.0-8-amd64

iwconfig:

```
wlx00aaab03226b  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

Which steps can be done to diagnose problem? Thanks you for any answers.

Comment: Is the driver loaded? Please run lsmod | grep rt2800usb .

Comment: @Alex [code]rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              28672  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             139264  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              69632  3 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
usbcore               323584  7 xhci_hcd,rt2800usb,usbhid,usb_storage,xhci_pci,uas,rt2x00usb [/code]

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I am using it.